# Tomcat(TomEE) error while creating JPA

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I have a simple Entity written in Eclipse(Java), and I try to start my project with tome, but I get this exception.

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.4.0-nonfinal-1598334-r422266:1599166 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected token: TO {stmnt 1004327302 ALTER TABLE Flight ADD COLUMN to VARCHAR(20)} [code=-5581, state=42581]
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:559)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:455)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:160)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:164)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newBrokerImpl(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:122)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:208)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:160)
at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManagerRegistry.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManagerRegistry.java:119)
at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManager.java:96)
at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.proxyIfNoTx(JtaEntityManager.java:326)
at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.createQuery(JtaEntityManager.java:280)
at com.airline.utils.DatabaseUtils.deleteData(DatabaseUtils.java:42)
at com.airline.utils.DatabaseUtils.addTestDataToDB(DatabaseUtils.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:308)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:303)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:308)
... 44 more
```

Here is my Flight Entity with which I hava this problem :

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Flight.getAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Flight f") })
public class Flight implements Serializable {

@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Flight() {
    super();
}

public Flight(FlightDestination to, Integer flightPrice, Date date) {
    super();
    this.flightPrice = flightPrice;
    this.date = date;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private FlightDestination to;

private Integer flightPrice;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;}
```

The problem is with my FlightDestination to field

FlightDestination:

```
public enum FlightDestination {
SOFIA, MUNICH, BERLIN, PARIS, VALENCIA, ROME, NEW_YORK, BARCELONA}
```

And this is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="airline">
<description>Container Persistence Unit</description>
<jta-data-source>airlineDatabase</jta-data-source>
<class>com.airline.models.Passenger</class>
<class>com.airline.models.Flight</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
    <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE" />
    <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrintParameters=true" />
</properties>
```

Passenger is my other Entity which work perfectly when I remove Flight Entity.

Comment: Sadly some JPA implementations don't auto-quote columns that have names that are SQL keywords, and your JPA implementation is one of these. Others (e.g DataNucleus) do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

`to` is a Keyword in mysql. Rename the property.

For more Information see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html